# Manipulating dictionary values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where

the value for each key is a list.

```
> {"Market":['market', 'shop', 'shopping']}
```

I want the values to be separated by pipe i.e

```
> {'Market':'market|shop|shopping'}
```

I tried out few lines of code

```
for keys, values in pydict.items():

   values =  "|".join(values)
   mynew[keys] = 
   print(keys, values)
```

I tried out but not getting the final answer.

Comment: what are you trying to get? Because you are only printing and not assigning them into the dict.

Comment: This is not a `machine-learning` question. (tag deleted)

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> x = {"Market":['market', 'shop', 'shopping'], "SomethingElse": ["foo", "bar"]}
>>> y = {k: "|".join(v) for (k, v) in x.items()}
{'Market': 'market|shop|shopping', 'SomethingElse': 'foo|bar'}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dict comprehension like @AKX pointed out or you can also modify the dict values in place.

```
    >>> x = {"Market":['market', 'shop', 'shopping'], "SomethingElse": ["foo", "bar"]}
    >>> for k,v in x.items():
    ...     x[k] = "|".join(v)
    ...
    >>> x
    {'Market': 'market|shop|shopping', 'SomethingElse': 'foo|bar'}
    >>>
```